# Can't build node when using pallet-nfts in custom pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, nft

I'm using pallet-nfts in my custom pallet. From the moment that I integrated pallet-nfts into my pallet it's not longer possible to build the node.

The custom pallet's Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "pallet-projects"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "FRAME pallet for projects"
authors = ["Sonemas LLC <hello@incentiverse.io>"]
homepage = "https://incentiverse.io"
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT"
publish = false
repository = "https://gitlab.com/incentiverse/node"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.6.1", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-nfts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-std = { version = "8.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
log = "0.4.20"
getrandom = { version = "0.2", features = ["js"] }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { version = "21.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-io = { version = "23.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-runtime = { version = "24.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-nfts/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

I added the line with `getrandom`as a solution to the following error that occurred:

```
  285 | /         compile_error!("the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by \
  286 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  287 | |                         For more information see: \
  288 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
```

However I'm still left with the following build error:

```
Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/rust/node/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/rust/node/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/rust/node/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-17bb0d6993cb0094/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/arjanvaneersel/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/arjanvaneersel/Development/rust/node/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.74.0-nightly (b3aa8e716 2023-09-21)


  --- stderr
     Compiling wasm-bindgen-backend v0.2.87
     Compiling thiserror v1.0.44
     Compiling toml v0.5.11
     Compiling impl-trait-for-tuples v0.2.2
     Compiling indexmap v1.9.3
     Compiling crypto-common v0.1.6
     Compiling block-buffer v0.10.4
     Compiling digest v0.9.0
     Compiling digest v0.10.7
     Compiling derive_more v0.99.17
     Compiling cranelift-entity v0.95.1
     Compiling errno v0.3.1
  error[E0583]: file not found for module `sys`
    --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:26:1
     |
  26 | mod sys;
     | ^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: to create the module `sys`, create file "/Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/sys.rs" or "/Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/sys/mod.rs"

  error[E0425]: cannot find function `with_description` in module `sys`
    --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:47:14
     |
  47 |         sys::with_description(*self, |desc| {
     |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

  error[E0425]: cannot find function `with_description` in module `sys`
    --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:58:14
     |
  58 |         sys::with_description(*self, |desc| match desc {
     |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

  error[E0425]: cannot find value `STRERROR_NAME` in module `sys`
    --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:64:22
     |
  64 |                 sys::STRERROR_NAME,
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

  error[E0425]: cannot find function `errno` in module `sys`
    --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:95:10
     |
  95 |     sys::errno()
     |          ^^^^^ not found in `sys`

  error[E0425]: cannot find function `set_errno` in module `sys`
     --> /Users/arjanvaneersel/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:100:10
      |
  100 |     sys::set_errno(err)
      |          ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0425, E0583.
  For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
  error: could not compile `errno` (lib) due to 6 previous errors
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I found some article suggesting that I should add the line `syn = { version = "=2.0.37" }` to Cargo.toml. I added this line first in the Cargo.toml of my custom pallet, then also in runtime, but the aforementioned error keeps coming back.

The command I'm using to build is `cargo build --release`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the repo so we can replicate the issue and debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing `default-features=false` on the pallet-nfts import. Try changing it to:

pallet-nfts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0", **default-features = false** }

Comment: How could I have missed that... Thank you for pointing that out, it solved the issue indeed.